# Show the inequality $P[|S_n-mn| \ge n \epsilon] \le \frac{ σ ^2}{n \epsilon^2}$

Tags: probability, statistics

Show the inequality $P[|S_n-mn| \ge n \epsilon ] \le \frac{ σ ^2}{n \epsilon ^2}$ for every $ \epsilon>0$ where

$S_n = X_1+...+X_n$ and $X_i$ are independant random variables under the same law. Also $m=E[X]$, $σ=Var[X]$

I think that i need to apply Chebyshev's inequality but i am not sure how...

Comment: Is $E[X_i] = m$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, edited now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite the statement you wish to prove as "$P\left[\left|\dfrac{1}{n}S_n - m\right| \ge \epsilon\right] \le \dfrac{\sigma^2/n}{\epsilon^2}$ for every $\epsilon > 0$".

Now, can you compute the mean and variance of $\dfrac{1}{n}S_n$?

Comment: The mean will be still $m$ but why will the variance become $\sigma^2/n$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a constant, then $\text{Var}[\alpha X] = \alpha^2\text{Var}[X]$. Also, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\text{Var}[X+Y] = \text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y]$. Those two facts should be enough for you to compute the variance of $\tfrac{1}{n}S_n$.